# Module 'gantt.table' is not available angularjs1.6

Tags: angularjs-1.6, angular-gantt

i have problem with package 'gantt.table' modules with angularjs1.6, i cant load all modules gantt like 'gantt.overlap',gantt.tooltips' ... i have the same problem.
    always i have the same problem with all modules gantt
    Help please

```
the error is:
Module 'gantt.table' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it
```

**app.js**

```
    import angular from 'angular';
    import uiRouter from 'angular-ui-router';
    import uiBootsrap from 'angular-ui-bootstrap';
    import fullCalendar from 'fullcalendar'; // eslint-disable-line
    import uiCalendar from 'angular-ui-calendar'; // eslint-disable-line
    import uiTree from 'angular-ui-tree'; // eslint-disable-line
    import smartTable from 'angular-smart-table';
    import ngAnimate from 'angular-animate';
    import ngSanitize from 'angular-sanitize';
    import uiSelect from 'ui-select';
    import moment from 'angular-moment';
    import socketFactory from 'angular-socket-io'; // eslint-disable-line
    import socketio from 'socket.io-client';
    import Common from './common/common';
    import Components from './components/components';
    import Filters from './filters/filters';
    import Services from './services/services';
    import AppComponent from './app.component';
    import AppConfig from './app.config';
    import gantt from 'angular-gantt';



    angular.module('dlp-portail', [
      uiRouter,
      uiBootsrap,
      'ui.calendar',
      'ui.tree',
      'ui.tree-filter',
      'gantt',
      'gantt.table',
      uiSelect,
      smartTable,
      ngAnimate,
      ngSanitize,
      'btford.socket-io',
      AppConfig.name,
      Common.name,
      Components.name,
      Filters.name,
      Services.name,
      moment,
    ])
```

the dependencies **package.json** file is:

```
{   
  "name": "ng6-starter",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Starter for Angular + ES6 + (Webpack or JSPM)",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.1.9",
    "angular": "1.6.1",
    "angular-animate": "^1.6.1",
    "angular-gantt": "^1.3.2",
    "angular-moment": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-resource": "1.6.1",
    "angular-sanitize": "1.6.1",
    "angular-smart-table": "2.1.11",
    "angular-socket-io": "0.7.0",
    "angular-ui-bootstrap": "1.3.3",
    "angular-ui-calendar": "1.0.2",
    "angular-ui-router": "0.3.2",
    "angular-ui-tree": "2.22.6",
    "crypto-js": "3.1.9-1",
    "jquery": "3.1.1",
    "lodash": "4.11.2",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "moment-range": "^4.0.1",
    "ui-select": "0.19.8"   
},   
"devDependencies": {
  "angular-mocks": "1.6.1",
  "ansi-regex": "2.1.1",
  "babel-core": "6.26.3",
  "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
  "babel-polyfill": "^6.8.0",
  "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
  "babel-register": "^6.8.0",
  "bootstrap-styl": "^5.0.5",
  "browser-sync": "^2.11.1",
  "chai": "^3.4.0",
  "chai-as-promised": "^5.3.0",
  "connect-history-api-fallback": "^1.1.0",
  "css-loader": "0.18.0",
  "css-modules-require-hook": "^4.0.0",
  "del": "^2.2.1",
  "dirty-chai": "^1.2.2",
  "eslint": "^2.7.0",
  "eslint-config-airbnb": "^9.0.1",
  "eslint-config-angular": "^0.5.0",
  "eslint-plugin-angular": "^1.0.1",
  "eslint-plugin-disable": "^0.3.0",
  "eslint-plugin-import": "^1.8.1",
  "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^1.5.3",
  "eslint-plugin-react": "^5.0.1",
  "eslint-plugin-require-jsdoc": "^1.0.4",
  "file-loader": "^0.8.5",
  "fs-walk": "0.0.1",
  "fullcalendar": "^3.0.1",
  "gulp": "^3.9.0",
  "gulp-eslint": "^2.0.0",
  "gulp-ng-config": "^1.3.1",
  "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
  "gulp-template": "^4.0.0",
  "gulp-util": "^3.0.7",
  "has-ansi": "^2.0.0",
  "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.16.1",
  "isparta-loader": "^2.0.0",
  "karma": "^0.13.9",
  "karma-chai": "^0.1.0",
  "karma-chai-as-promised": "^0.1.2",
  "karma-chrome-launcher": "^1.0.1",
  "karma-coverage": "^1.0.0",
  "karma-html-reporter": "^0.2.7",
  "karma-mocha": "^1.0.1",
  "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.0.0",
  "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.4",
  "karma-webpack": "^1.5.1",
  "merge": "^1.2.0",
  "minimist": "^1.2.0",
  "mocha": "^2.3.0",
  "moment": "^2.15.1",
  "ng-annotate-loader": "0.1.0",
  "node-libs-browser": "^1.0.0",
  "node-string-pad": "0.0.4",
  "path": "^0.12.7",
  "q": "^1.4.1",
  "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
  "run-sequence": "^1.1.0",
  "socket.io-client": "^1.4.6",
  "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
  "stylus": "^0.54.5",
  "stylus-loader": "^2.0.0",
  "supports-color": "^3.1.2",
  "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
  "webpack": "^1.9.5",
  "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.6.1",
  "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.6.0",
  "yargs": "^4.8.1"   
},   
"scripts": {
  "test": "karma start && eslint -c .eslintrc ."   
},   
  "keywords": [
    "angular",
    "webpack",
    "es6"   
  ],   
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/angularclass/NG6-starter.git"   
  },   
  "author": "AngularClass",   
  "license": "Apache-2.0" 
}
```

Comment: You'd better share your `package.json`.

Comment: vahdet u can see my package.json below thanks

Comment: problem resolved by adding import tooltips from 'angular-gantt/assets/angular-gantt-tooltips-plugin' in app.js